# How can it be that two models differ significantly with repsect to R2 but not RMSE?

Tags: variance, model-comparison, rms

I have two models.
Wilcoxon rank sum test says that the RMSE of these models (10-fold cross-validation) is not significant, but it is when using R2 instead of RMSE.
How can this be? Could it be that this has to do with that R2 also includes the variance of the depended variable?

Comment: Wilcoxon rank sum test tests the null that the distribution is symmetric about $\mu$. So where did you get these RMSE values from? Are you estimating in-sample RMSE values for 10 different fold models and testing whether these values are different than ... zero? If so, why?

Comment: No, I am comparing the performance (either RMSE or R2) for the ten folds of two different models.